# How to create an enum that uses the name of the member as the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I want to simplify the following class so that I don't need to type the value for every element and instead use the name of the enum member. This is similar to the [AutoNumber example](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#autonumber) in the documentation.

```
class Screen(Enum):
    MAIN = 'main'
    OPTIONS = 'options'
    GAME = 'game'
    SCORE = 'score'
```

Instead of the above, I'd like to do the following, so that e.g. `Screen.MAIN` is `'main'`:

```
class Screen(AutoNameValueEnum):
    MAIN = ()
    OPTIONS = ()
    GAME = ()
    SCORE = ()
```

I tried modifying the linked example, but I couldn't figure out how to get the name of the enum member.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible to modify that example for your case. `DuplicateFreeEnum`, on the other hand, looks like a more promising start.

Comment: But wait... Why do you want this? You can easily get the name from the items.

Comment: You're right, but I think it would be cleaner to use than e.g. `Screen.MAIN.name.lower()` or adding another attribute with that value. (If there's really no way, I'd be fine with it though.) I tried modifying `DuplicateFreeEnum`, but it does not allow to change the value. It raises `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Comment: @EthanFurman Could you post an answer where you are modifying the AutoNumber example with `__new__`? I couldn't figure out how to get the enum member name.

Comment: It isn't possible, which is why I said you can't do it with the `class` method (in my updated answer).  Apologies for my previous comment being incomplete.

Comment: @EthanFurman Why is my question marked as a duplicate when I asked it earlier? Just wondering.

Comment: The accepted answer on this question breaks `Enum`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an `Enum`, the members are also `Enum`s themselves. The example from the documentation uses the `__new__` method of the members to assign a value. You can't use that method, because the new member does not know how it is called within its owning class. Rather, use the initializer. Here's an example:

```
>>> class AutoNameValueEnum(enum.Enum):
...    def __init__(self):
...        self._value_ = self._name_.lower()
...
>>> class Color(AutoNameValueEnum):
...    RED = ()
...
>>> Color.RED
<Color.RED: 'red'>
```

**Update:**

Note that with this solution, value lookups are no longer possible. This is because the enum metaclass stores values before calling the initializer. This will effectively cut you out from pickling your enum and might also break things in some other places. An alternative (which breaks equivalence to similar strings, i.e. `a is "foo"`, for values, but nothing else) is to use an unhashable type for the values. The enum class will then do a linear search rather than try to lookup keys for values through a map.

```
class UnhashableString(str):
    def __hash__(self):
        raise TypeError

class AutoNameValueEnum(enum.Enum):
    def __init__(self):
        self._value_ = UnhashableString(self._name_.lower())

class Color(AutoNameValueEnum):
    RED = ()
```

Is the updated example for this alternative. All in all, I think that using the functional interface [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24250379/1881610) is the cleanest solution, because you can be sure that nothing breaks when you use it.

Comment: What the hell is `_value_` and `_name_` and why isn't it documented?

Comment: @OlehPrypin: A look at the source indicates that `_name_` and `_value_` are the attributes that back the `name` and `value` descriptors: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/enum.py#l499

Comment: They are the internal class members of enum members which the implementation (in the `enum` module) uses when the actual `name` and `value` properties are accessed. As for the missing documentation, I don't know why exactly they are not properly documented, but the `AutoNumber` example also uses the `_value_` property, so despite the [leading underscore in the name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python) they seem to be intended for use in subclasses..

Comment: Changing the `_value_` in `__init__` is not the proper way, and breaks `Enum`.  These types of changes should be done in `__new__` -- that is what `__new__` is for, as the AutoNumber example shows.

Comment: I feared that, but couldn't find anything that actually breaks. Could you give an example to show the problems?

Comment: Found it myself, for some reason in the source, the MetaClass first stores a copy of the value and then calls `__init__`. (It'd be interesting to know why it was implemented this way?!) This has the effect that the `_value2member_map_` has the wrong value, which makes value to key lookups fail. They are p.e. required in unpickling. To change this behaviour you'd have to override the meta class; I concur that the functional API provides a simpler solution here.

Comment: Another solution is to use an unhashable type for the values. The enum implementation will in this case use a linear search through the class members to do value lookups. I'll update my answer accordingly, but still think that the other solution is simpler.

Comment: When addressing comments to someone who is not the owner of the post you are commenting on (so me on your answer, or me on the question) make sure and address it with @UserName and then that person will be notified that a comment was directed to them.  I would have answered your question had I seen it (only stumbled on it just now by accident).

Comment: @Phillip Sadly, even with your latter version, lookup doesn't work. `Color(UnhashableString('red'))` works, but `Color('red')` gives `ValueError`.

Comment: I meant, it does work, but only by using UnhashableString.

Comment: @Joschua Yes. The point is that *automated* lookups will work, because they will use the previously serialized value, which is a  `UnhashableString`. If you really want to do manual lookups by a string value there is no alternative to either not using an enum or preparing a list of names and values before creating the class, as Ethan Furman suggested.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

Python 3.6 and [`aenum 2.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) have a new method that can be overridden to allow custom values for enum members making this process quite easy:

```
def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
    return name
```

- `name` is the name of the member
- `start` is the start value for the enumeration (defaults to `1`)
- `count` is the number of members so far
- `last_values` is a list of the member values so far

---

You cannot acheive this using the `class` method*, but you can using the [Functional API](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html#functional-api):

```
Color = enum.Enum(
    'Color',
    ((name, name.lower()) for name in 'BLACK RED GREEN BLUE'.split()),
    )
```

*Okay, like most things in Python if you try hard enough you can, but why go to all that extra work?